# Pass value of p:selectOneMenu item in parameter function

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I want to refresh my table when I select a value in the dropdown, and in the table I want to call a function with the selected value as a parameter.

The value I select has to come in the function `calculateAveragePrice` as a parameter.

This is my dropdown with all the different regions.

```
<p:selectOneMenu id="list" value="#{regionController.region}">
    <f:selectItems value="#{regionController.regions}" var="region" itemLabel="#{region.name}"/>
    <f:ajax execute="list" render="myTable" />
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

This is the table I want to refresh:

```
 <table id="myTable" class="table table-responsive">
     <tr>
         <td>#{msg.averagePrice}:</td>
         <td>#{flightController.calculateAveragePrice(regionController.region)}</td>
     </tr>
 </table>
```

RegionController bean:

```
@Named
@RequestScoped
public class RegionController {
    @Inject
    RegionService regionService;

    private Region region;
    private Collection<Region> regions;

    @PostConstruct
    public void initialize() {
        regions = regionService.findAll();
    }

    public Region getRegion() {
        return region;
    }

    public void setRegion(Region region) {
        this.region = region;
    }

    public void setRegions(Collection<Region> regions) {
        this.regions = regions;
    }
    public Collection<Region> getRegions() {
        return regions;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i got it right, it's just a design issue.

You could just create a property called `region` inside `flightController`.

Then, you would have:

```
<p:selectOneMenu id="list" value="#{FLIGHTCONTROLLER.region}">
     <f:selectItems value="#{regionController.regions}" var="region" itemLabel="#{region.name}"/>
     <f:ajax execute="list" render="myTable" />
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

Now, you don't have to pass the regions as parameter, because FlightController already have that property setted via ajax.

The way you did, you're setting regionController.Region for no reason.

Comment: Are missing a converter in this case, don't?